# FXcop option is not shown under General setting in SonarQube hosted site

Tags: sonarqube, fxcop

[image]

I'm not able to see FxCop option under General setting in SonarQube hosted site. Because of this I'm not able to set FxCop installation directory path to SonarQube hosted site. Also when I'm running sonarRunner with FxCop custom rule enabled in SonarSite it throws an FxCop related error.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to set the path to FxCop. It won't be activated during a sonarqube.com analysis because [there are no FxCop rules in the C# profile](https://nemo.sonarqube.org/coding_rules#qprofile=cs-sonar-way-31865%7Cactivation=true).

Comment: So how we will integrate sonarQube with Fxcop.

Comment: Also when I'm creating custom rules using FxCop I get error for Microsoft.Cci.dll issue. Even though its added as a reference it throws an error.

Comment: Could you please tell me how to create custom rules using Roslyn. There is no sample example available on net.

Comment: These are new and distinct questions. You should open new SO questions for them or head over to the [SonarQube Google Group](https://groups.google.com/forum/?pli=1#!forum/sonarqube)